# How do I get the category URL from get_the_category?

Tags: categories, loop, slug, single

My loop below shows the latest 4 posts from the same category as the post currently being viewed. Its located within single.php.

I'm trying to get the URL of that same category so I can link back to category.php to view all posts from that same category. I thought grabbing the category slug would work but my code below doesn't output anything:

```
<?php
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category();

    foreach ($categories as $category) :

       $exclude = get_the_ID();
       $posts = get_posts('posts_per_page=4&category='. $category->term_id);

        foreach($posts as $post) :
         if( $exclude != get_the_ID() ) { ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="post c-1"> Link to actual post</a>

    <?php } endforeach; ?>

<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/categories/<?php echo $childcat->cat_slug; ?>" title="View all" class="btn border"><i class="i-right-double-arrow"></i> View all <?php echo $childcat->cat_slug; ?></a>
<?php  endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843320/get-category-link-wordpress#comment49730458_30843320) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14816837/1010918) really helped to understand this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
get_category_link( $category_id );
```

See:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link

In your specific case:

```
<?php
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category();

    foreach ($categories as $category) :

       $exclude = get_the_ID();
       $posts = get_posts('posts_per_page=4&category='. $category->term_id);

        foreach($posts as $post) :
         if( $exclude != get_the_ID() ) { ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="post c-1"> Link to actual post</a>

    <?php } endforeach; ?>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ); ?>" title="View all" class="btn border"><i class="i-right-double-arrow"></i> View all <?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
<?php  endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**A STRAIGHT FORWARD AND CLEAN CODE**

I'm a newbie :)

I modified the codes given by Adam and removed the unnecessary parts not needed to answer the initial question.

***It worked for me 100%.***

Give it a try.

Please let me know if it worked for you too :)

```
<?php $categories = get_the_category();
foreach ($categories as $category) :
endforeach; ?>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ); ?>">
  LINK TO CURRENT POST CATEGORY >>
</a>
```

OR

```
<?php $categories = get_the_category();
foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>

The category is:
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ); ?>">
  <?php echo $category->name; ?>
</a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

COMBINE SOME OTHER ELEMENTS AS YOU LIKE. PLAY AROUND BUDDY.

Comment: I don't understand the empty foreach. How does that work? Does that just select the last entry in $categories as $category, so you're only showing the link for the last category?

Comment: Looks like foreach is compulsory. Without it, the code will not work properly. You can use any thing as the term. You can decide to change to $category = get_the_category(); foreach ($category as $category) :  I hope this helps. Don't forget, I am a newbie. Just playing around with stuffs. If you noticed, I removed one irrelevant line of code. Have fun.